# Как брать только первую категорию и списка? (php)

Tags: php

```html
function get_modul1($table, $xml)
    {
        global $db;
        $lastmod = date("Y-m-d");

        $cats = $db->super_query('select id, options from ' . PREFIX . '_' . $table . '_options where type="category"', true);
        $posts = $db->super_query('select alt_name, category from ' . PREFIX . '_' . $table . '_post where approve="1"', true);
        $postsCat = [];

        foreach ($posts as $post) {
            $postsCat[$post['category']][] = $post['alt_name'];
        }
        unset($posts);


        $table .= '/';

        $loc = $this->home . $table;
        $xml .= $this->get_xml($loc, $lastmod);
        foreach ($cats as $cat) {
            $cat_alt = explode('|||alt_name=', $cat['options'])[1];
            $cat_alt = explode('|||', $cat_alt)[0];

            $loc = $this->home . $table . $cat_alt . '/';
            $xml .= $this->get_xml($loc, $lastmod);
            foreach ($postsCat[$cat['id']] as $post) {
                $loc = $this->home . $table . $cat_alt . '/' . $post . '/';
    
                $xml .= $this->get_xml($loc, $lastmod);
            }
        }
        return $xml;
    }
```

Делаю карту сайта, все категории выводятся нормально, а вот с постами проблема, посты добавлены в несколько категорий: 12,23,34,35,55 и тд.
Когда код хочет сформировать урл возникает трабл, т.к. он ищет именно категорию например 12, а когда делает запрос в посте 12,23,34,35,55 и тд. и таким образом он не может определить в какой категории пост.

Мне нужно чтобы урл формировался по первой категории, а остальные категории что идут после запятой не принимались во внимание.

Всю голову сломал.

Answer (score 1):

Непонятно, в каком виде хранятся категории в колонке `category`. Если как строка с перечислением через запятую, то

```
foreach ($posts as $post) {
  $postFirstCat = explode(',', $post['category'])[0];
  $postsCat[$postFirstCat][] = $post['alt_name'];
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, в дуплил как как это)